# LIQUIBASE: How to install liquibase. I'm having an error with the batch file I created

Tags: oracle, batch-file, oracle11g, liquibase

here is the error saying liquibase is not recognized as an internal/external
command in cmd

http://animobile.info/upload/1/error.bmp

lb_update.bat code1:

```
    @echo off call Liquibase --changeLogFile=update.xml
```

update.xml coode:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.Liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.Liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9                http://www.Liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
    <include file="v000/master.xml" />
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

master.xml code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
     <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.Liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.Liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9 http://www.Liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
     <preConditions>
    <!-- These changes should only be run against a schema with major version 0 -->
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">
        SELECT NVL(MAX(id),0)
        FROM databasechangelog
        WHERE author='MajorVersion '
       </sqlCheck>  
       </preConditions >
      <include file="v000/2009-10-15-73.xml"   />
       </databaseChangeLog>
```

The expected result when the lb_update.bat is executed, a confirmation message will appear saying: Migration successful.

How can i fix this please help! Thank you!

Comment: Is liquibase.bat in your PATH? If not, it may help to use the full path when you reference it in your call command.

Comment: Does "call" require the .bat extension? Like "@echo off call Liquibase.bat --changeLogFile=update.xml"

Comment: Mr. @NathanVoxland, I'm following this tutorial but I'm stucked on the part where I will execute the lb_update.bat http://www.liquibase.org/tutorial-using-oracle

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned the full path of `Liquibase.bat` file, it will be searched in the current directory which is `D:\Projects\lbdemo\trunk` in your case. Looks like `Liquibase.bat` file doesn't exist at the Location `D:\Projects\lbdemo\trunk`.